# Modulo in finding most repeated number in array

Tags: arrays, data-structures, max, repeat

Can someone please explain to me how this is done? Here is the code snippet i am trying to understand:

```
// Iterate though input array, for every element
    // arr[i], increment arr[arr[i]%k] by k where k is less than of equal to number of elements
    // ie. k <= n
    for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
        arr[(arr[i]%k)] += k;

    // Find index of the maximum repeating element
    int max = arr[0], result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
            result = i;
        }
    }
```

I realize that when we iterate through an array the fist time we

1. take a value of each element we iterate modulo k.
2. use this as an index;
3. take an element at the index and
   increment it by k.

And after we are done the index of the highest number element is the most frequent number we are looking for.

I understand the steps but i do not understand the logic especially around that modulo and indexes vs values. Any explanation will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the algorithm to work, we also need a condition that `0 <= a[i] < k`. Can you confirm that in your problem statement?

Comment: It will be good to have the source of the algorithm mentioned in the problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will work only if it is guaranteed that `0 <= arr[i] < k` or that ranges for `arr[i]` lie in an interval of `k` values.

The algorithm uses the same array (`arr`) as a frequency hashmap to store the number of occurences of a particular value, albeit using the modulo operation. Any number when incremented by the divisor will give the same remainder every time. Each time an occurence is found, the element at `arr[i] % k` is incremented by k. This is analogous to incrementing frequency hashmap by `1`. At the end of the iteration, all elements will be incremented by `(number of times value occurs) * k`. Finding the maximum element, will then will give you the most occurring element.

There are assumptions in this algorithm that you haven't mentioned:

1. `0 < arr[i] <= k`
2. `k <= n`
3. In case there is a tie between most repeated elements, the element with the largest value is picked up.
4. The result can overflow if the `(count of occurences) * k + arr[i]` is greater than `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Mukul thank you so much for your answer. I understand that same modulo is going to point to the same index in the final array, what i don't understand is why are we reusing the same array? Is this for minimizing the space? Here's the link to the source: [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-repeating-number-in-ok-time/)   Also, when

Comment: Also, when we use modulo of a number to determine the index, and then use that index to say which number was most frequent, how is it guaranteed that that modulo will represent the value of the most frequent number? In the source the modulo of the most frequent number is equal to that number, but what if the modulo of a number is different? In the example - most frequent number is 3, and k is 8. 3%8 is 3. Third is the index in final array and the result. What if the most freq number is 11? 11%8 is 3, which is the wrong result for 11?

Comment: @programming2016: yes, it is for saving space. The algorithm wants to use O(1) space. You are missing a very important detail in your question. `0 <= arr[I] < k` and `k < n`. With this constraint, example stated by you can never occur as original value of an element lies exactly in the range of modulo. The choice of `k` is important.

Comment: Thank you Mukul for great answers! Very helpful.

Comment: @programming2016, (assuming that new to stackoverflow) if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Yes it does answer my question. Where is the check mark? I can't see any.